# Parse addresses through Google Places API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I have a huge(50k) db with addresses like

```
12340 Via Moura, San Diego, CA, United States
17029 Avenida Cordillera, San Diego, CA, United States
3324 Sandleheath, Sarasota, FL 34235, USA
```

They were autocompleted with google Places Autocomplete js api and then stored in db.
Now I need to get distinct parts `state`, `city`, `zip`... etc of these addresses. 
Is it possible to do with some google of API? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution.
Need to do two API calls to google places API.
First call to get PLACE_ID by full address, second one get all data about address by PLACE_ID.

```
        $params = [
            'key' => env('GOOGLE_API_KEY'),
            'query' => 'FULL_ADDRESS',
            'types' => 'address'
        ];
        $guzzle_client = new Client();
        $res = $guzzle_client->request('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?parameters',
            [
                'query' => $params
            ]
        );

        $prediction = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
        if ($prediction['status'] == 'OK') {
            $paramsID = [
                'key' => env('GOOGLE_API_KEY'),
                'placeid' => $prediction['results'][0]['place_id'],
            ];
            $guzzle_clientID = new Client();
            $resID = $guzzle_clientID->request('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json',
                [
                    'query' => $paramsID
                ]
            );

            $predictionID = json_decode($resID->getBody(), true);

            $address_components = $predictionID['result']['address_components'];
            $address = [];
            foreach ($address_components as $component) {
                switch ($component['types'][0]) {
                    case 'street_number':
                        $address['street_number'] = $component['short_name'];
                        break;
                    case 'route':
                        $address['street_name'] = $component['short_name'];
                        break;
                    case 'locality':
                        $address['city'] = $component['short_name'];
                        break;
                    case 'administrative_area_level_1':
                        $address['state'] = $component['short_name'];
                        break;
                    case 'postal_code':
                        $address['zip'] = $component['short_name'];
                        break;
                }
            }
            $addresses[]= $address;
        } else {
            dd('Not found place');
        }
```